# How to override custom module class in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, model

I want to override a model class of custom module.

Want to override:-***I95DevConnect\Base\Model\Product\product***

By:-***I95Dev\Base\Model\Rewrite\Product\product***

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="I95DevConnect\Base\Model\Product\Product" 
             type="I95Dev\Base\Model\Rewrite\Product\Product" />
</config>
```

**I95DevConnect\Base\Model\Product\product.php**

```
<?php
    namespace I95DevConnect\Base\Model\Product;

    use I95DevConnect\Base\Helper\Data;
    use Magento\Tax\Model\ClassModelFactory as TaxClassModelFactory;

    class Product
    {

        /**
         * Custom logs
         */
        const MAGLOGNAME = 'MagentoToERP';
        const ERPLOGNAME = 'ERPToMagento';
        const I95EXC = 'i95devApiException';

        protected $_logger;

        /**
         * Tax class model factory
         *
         * @var TaxClassModelFactory
         */
        private $_taxClassModelFactory;

        /**
         * @var \I95DevConnect\MessageQueue\Api\Data\ProductInterface
         */
        protected $_productInterface;

        /**
         * @var StockRegistryProviderInterface
         */
        protected $_stockRegistryProvider;
        /**
         *
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                              $logger
         * @param TaxClassModelFactory                                  $taxClassModelFactory
         * @param \I95DevConnect\MessageQueue\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productInterface
         * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryProvider $stockRegistryProvider
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Tax\Model\ClassModelFactory $taxClassModelFactory,
            \I95DevConnect\MessageQueue\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productInterface,
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryProvider $stockRegistryProvider
        ) {
            $this->_logger = $logger;
            $this->_taxClassModelFactory = $taxClassModelFactory;
            $this->_productInterface = $productInterface;
            $this->_stockRegistryProvider = $stockRegistryProvider;
        }

        /**
         * Sets Product information
         *
         * @param  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
         * @return array
         */
        public function setProduct($product)
        {
            try {
                $weight = 0;
                $status = $product->getStatus();
                $productStatus = $product->getVisibility();
                $websiteId = 1;
                $productId = $product->getId();
                $stockData = $this->_stockRegistryProvider->getStockItem($productId, $websiteId);

                if ($productStatus == 1) {
                    $productVisibility = 0;
                } else {
                    $productVisibility = 1;
                }
                $productId = $product->getId();
                $taxClassModel = $this->_taxClassModelFactory->create()->load($product->getTaxClassId());
                $taxClass = $taxClassModel->getClassName();
                $taxClassName = (isset($taxClass) ? $taxClass : 'None' );
                $specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
                $productSpecialPrice = (isset($specialPrice) ? $specialPrice : '0' );
                $this->_productInterface->setSku($product->getsku());
                $this->_productInterface->setName($product->getName());
                $this->_productInterface->setDescription(strip_tags($product->getDescription()));
                $this->_productInterface->setShortDescription(strip_tags($product->getShortDescription()));
                $this->_productInterface->setQty($stockData->getQty());
                $cost = $product->getCost();
                $this->_productInterface->setCost((isset($cost) ? $cost : 0));
                $this->_productInterface->setUpdatedAt($product->getUpdatedAt());
                $this->_productInterface->setTypeId($product->getTypeId());
                $this->_productInterface->setSpecialPrice($productSpecialPrice);
                $this->_productInterface->setPrice($product->getPrice());
                $this->_productInterface->setSpecialFromDate($product->getSpecialFromDate());
                $this->_productInterface->setSpecialToDate($product->getSpecialToDate());
                $this->_productInterface->setUnitOfMeasure('each');
                $this->_productInterface->setQuantityOrdered(0);
                if ($product->getWeight()) {
                    $weight = $product->getWeight();
                }
                $this->_productInterface->setWeight($weight);
                $this->_productInterface->setTaxClassId($taxClassName);
                $this->_productInterface->setCreatedAt($product->getcreatedAt());
                $this->_productInterface->setStatus($status);
                $this->_productInterface->setDiscountReasonCodeId(null);
                $this->_productInterface->setDefaultDiscountReasonCode(null);
                $this->_productInterface->setDiscountAmount(0);
                $this->_productInterface->setIsTierPriceApplied(true);
                $this->_productInterface->setVoucherNumber(null);
                $this->_productInterface->setGiftCardAmount(0);
                $this->_productInterface->setStoreId($stockData->getStoreId());
                $this->_productInterface->setBackorders($stockData->getBackorders());
                $this->_productInterface->setSourceItemId($productId);
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                $this->_logger->critical($ex->getMessage());
            }
            return $this->_productInterface;
        }
    }
```

**I95Dev\Base\Model\Rewrite\Product\product.php**

```
<?php
namespace I95Dev\Base\Model\Rewrite\Product;

use I95DevConnect\Base\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Tax\Model\ClassModelFactory as TaxClassModelFactory;

    class Product extends \I95DevConnect\Base\Model\Product\Product
{

    /**
     * Custom logs
     */
    const MAGLOGNAME = 'MagentoToERP';
    const ERPLOGNAME = 'ERPToMagento';
    const I95EXC = 'i95devApiException';

    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * Tax class model factory
     *
     * @var TaxClassModelFactory
     */
    private $_taxClassModelFactory;

    /**
     * @var \I95DevConnect\MessageQueue\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     */
    protected $_productInterface;

    /**
     * @var StockRegistryProviderInterface
     */
    protected $_stockRegistryProvider;
    /**
     *
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                              $logger
     * @param TaxClassModelFactory                                  $taxClassModelFactory
     * @param \I95DevConnect\MessageQueue\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productInterface
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryProvider $stockRegistryProvider
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\ClassModelFactory $taxClassModelFactory,
        \I95DevConnect\MessageQueue\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productInterface,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryProvider $stockRegistryProvider
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_taxClassModelFactory = $taxClassModelFactory;
        $this->_productInterface = $productInterface;
        $this->_stockRegistryProvider = $stockRegistryProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Sets Product information
     *
     * @param  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        try {
            $weight = 0;
            $status = $product->getStatus();
            $productStatus = $product->getVisibility();
            $websiteId = 1;
            $AdditionalAtrr=0;
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $stockData = $this->_stockRegistryProvider->getStockItem($productId, $websiteId);

            if ($productStatus == 1) {
                $productVisibility = 0;
            } else {
                $productVisibility = 1;
            }
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $taxClassModel = $this->_taxClassModelFactory->create()->load($product->getTaxClassId());
            $taxClass = $taxClassModel->getClassName();
            $taxClassName = (isset($taxClass) ? $taxClass : 'None' );
            $specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
            $productSpecialPrice = (isset($specialPrice) ? $specialPrice : '0' );
            //$this->_productInterface->setSku($product->getsku());
            $this->_productInterface->setName($product->getName());
            $this->_productInterface->setDescription(strip_tags($product->getDescription()));
            $this->_productInterface->setShortDescription(strip_tags($product->getShortDescription()));
            $this->_productInterface->setQty($stockData->getQty());
            $cost = $product->getCost();
            $this->_productInterface->setCost((isset($cost) ? $cost : 0));
            $this->_productInterface->setUpdatedAt($product->getUpdatedAt());
            $this->_productInterface->setTypeId($product->getTypeId());
            $this->_productInterface->setSpecialPrice($productSpecialPrice);
            $this->_productInterface->setPrice($product->getPrice());
            $this->_productInterface->setSpecialFromDate($product->getSpecialFromDate());
            $this->_productInterface->setSpecialToDate($product->getSpecialToDate());
            $this->_productInterface->setUnitOfMeasure('each');
            $this->_productInterface->setQuantityOrdered(0);
            if ($product->getWeight()) {
                $weight = $product->getWeight();
            }

            $this->_productInterface->setWeight($weight);
//             if ($product->getTestDemo()) {
//                $AdditionalAtrr = $product->getTestDemo();
//            }
//            $this->_productInterface->setAdditionalAtrr($AdditionalAtrr);
            $this->_productInterface->setTaxClassId($taxClassName);
            $this->_productInterface->setCreatedAt($product->getcreatedAt());
            $this->_productInterface->setStatus($status);
            $this->_productInterface->setDiscountReasonCodeId(null);
            $this->_productInterface->setDefaultDiscountReasonCode(null);
            $this->_productInterface->setDiscountAmount(0);
            $this->_productInterface->setIsTierPriceApplied(true);
            $this->_productInterface->setVoucherNumber(null);
            $this->_productInterface->setGiftCardAmount(0);
            $this->_productInterface->setStoreId($stockData->getStoreId());
            $this->_productInterface->setBackorders($stockData->getBackorders());
            $this->_productInterface->setSourceItemId($productId);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
              $this->_logger->critical($ex->getMessage());
        }
        return $this->_productInterface;
    }
}
```

Can any one help me on this problem ? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We can override classes using the Preferences in Magento2.
Use the following code in your di.xml

```
<preference for="I95DevConnect\Base\Model\Product\Product" 
         type="I95Dev\Base\Model\Rewrite\Product\Product" />
```

Please mention the dependency in your module.xml so that it will load after the base module have been loaded. Please mention in module.xml as following:

```
<module name="I95Dev_Base" setup_version="1.13.2">
    <sequence>
        <module name="I95DevConnect_Base" />
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks  for answer but i have made changes it is not working.

Comment: Please clear the var/generation folder and check if the same class is overridden by any other class.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check once.